# Type assertions and optional chaining in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining, type-assertion

I have the following function that performs a simple type assertion, checking that a variable is not undefined or null.

```
const isDefinedAndNotNull = <T>(val: T | null | undefined): val is NonNullable<T> =>
    (val !== null) && (typeof val !== "undefined");
```

However, I have an issue when using this function to assert the presence of a nested object using optional chaining. The below code will cause Typescript to not compile:

```
type MaybeNullThing = {
    myProp?: {
        coolThing?: string
    }
}

const thing: MaybeNullThing = getThing();

if (isDefinedAndNotNull(thing?.myProp?.coolThing)) {
    console.log(thing.myProp.coolThing); // error: thing.myProp could be undefined
}
```

However, Typescript has no problem with the following:

```
if (thing?.myProp?.coolThing) {
    console.log(thing.myProp.coolThing); // defined here
}
```

My question is essentially how to get the type assertion to assert that both the nested object and the target object are defined, if this is possible. Thanks!

[Link to a TS Playground containing the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAIgUwGZzMgJgQTFgORCgIFcAbcmAXhgB4AVAGgD4AKANwENyAuGBjAA%20MMBSojS%20NBmwBKftyoIYRMGUpcARuWSMWNFgFgAUDHMxOPGAEJqtMZTkwAZC8tQAngAdkIVDBKtvYwAERSWDKYWKFyANympl6%20MACyXJ5ayBrkDAAWGADmNDAA3qYWMAC2ngAKAE4g3gD8-OVmlRagILkFYIWtMND1RRUWAL6mkyamoJCwUH2F-OmZ2eL5RSXt5jUNTW1j5t29RfyhwFwQyAC0oOQgpPW6EBA3hfXIyGChY9PjCRmJjgATYCBQ6GieEIxBybEWRWaADo9o0WkiTpt%20nJnDsuuAID1kEiHoV4UsUXU0RiQD0sYV4jAAPRMmDIeqNer8BH9Sn7bwwUAULAwLIwCJRbBTIA)

Comment: Could you maybe use a callback variant instead of an if?

Comment: I like this idea: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgMwAoCcCmE1lgXhgHgBUAaAPgAoA3AQwBsAuGQmAHxjAFdbbWYOwAJmgRwwaAcXgIAIsNHjGVOo0IBKGDlIxKIOANWMdejVoDeAWABQMKTHJKeAQhx5O3dQDIPdqAE8ADmggCNp0MM54AET8QiJiApGq6hbWNmmIsnHiDqoA3FY2AL5WxZZWfoEwALLUvgBGaAByXLSEABaiAOYaMClpMAC2vqgg-gD8jH39aaAgrR1gnRMw0ChdBWmlpVagkLBQC52MNfVNLe1dPVNDI-6TGzaz812MkcDUmAC0oLQgHCi0DAQT6ddBYSIbLb5MqWRCoDBYKDkA5dMYAOhuKFG6KeF0WxA2ORMMF2EDmaDRv06OSseSAA

but maybe an unwieldy API

Comment: Yeah, it's very similar to what I just knocked up :), you could also get rid of the brackets `val => console.log(val)`.  If you think about it, it's not that unwieldy even React use this with there `useEffect`, there just not passing any value..

Comment: Actually just extending the idea a little bit, you could maybe pass the props as an array in case you wanted to check for multiple, and use array destructuring in the callback.  I think that would be pretty neat & tidy.

Answer (score 1):

The type assertion only really covers the deepest level; the property you're passing to the assertion.
Your condition *only* confirms `coolThing` is defined and not `null`.

To cover `myProp`, you'd need to explicitly check that as well:

```
if (isDefinedAndNotNull(thing?.myProp) && isDefinedAndNotNull(thing?.myProp?.coolThing)) {
  console.log(thing.myProp.coolThing);
}
```

TS is naïve like that, and I honestly don't know of a way around it.

Comment: Yep, what I thought sadly :'). Cheers for your answer nonetheless.